# React nested items rerender not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rerender

im trying to develop component that will sort new items, depending if item parent is or is not present on the list already. Components can be nested in each other to unlimited depth. Parent have list of children, children have parentId. Now, it works as expected at the first render, but when new item appear on the list (its added by user, using form, up in the structure), it does in fact make its way to components list, but is not shown on the screen until page reload. I can see temporary list that is used to make all calculations have the item as expected in the nested structure. Then i set state list to value of temp, but its not working, and i dont know why. Im quite new to react stuff. In act of desperation i even tried to destructure root parent of the item, hoping it will force rerender, but that didnt worked too. Anybody could help with this?

http://jsfiddle.net/zkfj03um/13/

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Component(props) {
    const [component, setComponent] = useState(props.component);
    return (
        <div>
            {component.id};
            {component.name};
            <ul>
                {component.subcomps && component.subcomps.map((comp) =>
                    <li key={comp.id} style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>
                        <Component component={comp}
                            id={comp.id}
                            name={comp.name}
                            parentId={comp.parentId}
                            subcomps={comp.subcomps}
                        />
                   </li>)}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

function ComponentsList(props) {
    const newComponents = props.newComponents;
    const [filteredComponents, setFilteredComponents] = useState();

    function deepSearch(collection, key, value, path=[]) {
        for (const o of collection) {
          for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(o)) {
            if (k === key && v === value) {
              return {path: path.concat(o), object: o};
            }
            if (Array.isArray(v)) {
              const _o = deepSearch(v, key, value, path.concat(o));
              if (_o) {
                return _o;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

    async function filter() {
        let temp = [];
        await newComponents.forEach((comp) => {
            //parent may be, or may not be on the list. Its not necesary
            const parentTuple = deepSearch(filteredComponents, 'id', comp.parentId);
            if (!parentTuple) {
                //create parent substitute logic
            } else {
                const parent = parentTuple.object;
                const root = parentTuple.path[0];
                const mutReplies = [comm, ...parent.replies];
                parent.replies = mutReplies;
                temp = [{...root}, ...temp]
            }
        })
        setFilteredComponents([...temp])
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      }, [filteredComponents]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        filter();
      }, [newComponents]);

    return (<>
        {!loading && filteredComponents.map((component, index) =>
            <li key={index}>
                <Component component={component} />
            </li>
        )}
    </>);
}



const items = [
    { id: 1, name: 'sample1', subcomps: [{ id: 5, name: 'subcomp1', parentId: 1, subcomps: [] }] },
    {
        id: 2, name: 'sample2', subcomps: [
            { id: 6, name: 'subcomp2', subcomps: [], parentId: 2 },
            { id: 7, name: 'subcomp3', subcomps: [], parentId: 2 }
        ]
    },

]
ReactDOM.render(<ComponentsList newComponents={items} />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Comment: You can't await for `forEach`

Comment: @Konrad i tried to delete this and set timeout for 10 seconds so this loop surely had time to work - no effect